# How to Force UISearchDisplayController to Update

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I am creating a search controller and I want to do autocomplete.

It's fine.

However I got data from several sources. First I got data from local cache. Then I load data from the web.

So when we finish downloading data we want to make the searchcontroller to reload it's table incorporating new data.

How do we do that?

Comment: Is your question about the `UISearchDisplayController` in iOS?

Comment: You are correct UISearchDisplayController . This is what happen when you program in iMac and ask question in windows 7. I will update the question. Also the tags are all wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just call `reloadData` on the search display controller's table view:

```
[self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
```

Comment: searchDisplayController is now depreciated in iOS 8.0

Comment: check out UISearchController - here is an example, https://github.com/kharrison/CodeExamples/tree/08bf85147af2fc98dbc33f38f52acc781e27b853/WorldFacts and a tutorial http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2015/02/16/updating-to-the-ios-8-search-controller.html